# Finding an explicit factorisation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

We have shown that A= C[x,y]/(x²+y²-1) is a UFD (C means complex numbers). 
x is not a prime element here because A/(x)≈CxC which is not an ID.
Hence it turns out that x is not an irreducible.

1. What is an explicit factorisation?
2. How could one "guess" such a factorisation?

Comment: Is it a UFD? What about $x\cdot x=(1-y)(1+y)$?

Comment: Yeah. Turns out x is actually NOT irreducible in this ring. That's what I have to show.

Comment: To see that A is a UFD go with the following steps- take x²+y²-1 = (x+iy)(x-iy)-1.

Comment: But your reason for saying $x$ is not irreducible seems to be linked to your assertion that the ring is a UFD.

Comment: Consider x²+y²-1 = (x+iy)(x-iy)-1. Then let x+iy=u,x-iy=v. Then A ≈ C[u,v]/(uv-1) which is actually a localisation of C[u] at u. Now localisation of UFD is UFD.

Comment: OK, how's this: $x=(1/2)(x+iy+i)(x+iy-i)(x-iy)$.

Comment: I think this works. Just have to show that they are not units. How to do that?

Comment: Well, $x-iy$ is a unit, since $(x-iy)(x+iy)=x^2+y^2=1$. The other two factors are either both units, in which case $x$ is a unit, or neither is a unit. If $x$ were a unit, then $A/(x)$ would be trivial.

Comment: So, do we have a solution now?

Comment: Yes. You can add it as a comment.

Comment: Or you could write it up, and post it as an answer.